# python memoization and memory leaks

Tags: python, memory-leaks, memoization

My goal is to memoize the object instantiation such that there is only one object with the same initialization arguments.

I adapted some code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879137/how-can-i-memoize-a-class-instantiation-in-python), and the following code works. Basically, `memoize` is a decorator that caches the initialization arguments. Next time the same initialization arguments are used, the cached object is returned, instead of creating a new one.

```
from functools import wraps                                                        

def memoize(function):                                                             
    memo = {}                                                                      

    @wraps(function)                                                               
    def wrapper(*args):                                                            
        if args in memo:                                                           
            return memo[args]                                                      
        else:                                                                      
            rv = function(*args)                                                   
            memo[args] = rv                                                        
            return rv                                                              
    return wrapper                                                                 


@memoize                                                                           
class Test(object):                                                                
    def __init__(self, v):                                                         
        self.v = v                                                                 

class TT(object):                                                                  
    def __init__(self, v):                                                         
        self.t = Test(v)                                                           

tests= [Test(1), Test(2), Test(3), Test(2), Test(4)]                               

for test in tests:                                                                 
    print test.v, id(test)                                                         

tt = TT(2)                                                                         
print id(tt.t)
```

And I got desired results

```
1 4355094288
2 4355094416
3 4355094544
2 4355094416
4 4355094672
4355094416
```

The question I have is that do I need to manually clear the cache `memoize.memo`? It seems that it will contain the references and prevent memory to be released. Is there a way to make this resource release more automated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either a lru/mru dict (https://github.com/amitdev/lru-dict) or use a time limited cache object. There are great examples here https://pythonhosted.org/cachetools/ and here [Limiting the size of a python dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437617/limiting-the-size-of-a-python-dictionary).