# How do you find the first item in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I am trying to get the first item I inserted in my dictionary (which hasn't been re-ordered).
For instance:

```
_dict = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
```

I would like to get the tuple `('a',1)`

How can I do that?

Comment: This has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362391/how-do-you-find-the-first-key-in-a-dictionary)

Comment: @yatu indeed, in fact I mentioned it in my own answer. However they do not make the distinction between python 2, 3, and >=3.6, hence this was my contribution after getting confused at that answer you mentioned, and looking around a bit more

Comment: The first don't, but it looks like it is covered in the third answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30362701/9698684

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Before Python 3.6**, dictionaries were un-ordered, therefore "first" was not well defined. If you wanted to keep the insertion order, you would have to use an `OrderedDict`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

**Starting from Python 3.6**, the dictionaries keep the insertion order by default ( see [How to keep keys/values in same order as declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/how-to-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared) )

Knowing this, you just need to do

```
first_element = next(iter(_dict.items()))
```

Note that since `_dict.items()` is not an iterator but is iterable, you need to make an iterator for it by calling `iter`.

The same can be done with keys and values:

```
first_key = next(iter(_dict))
first_value = next(iter(_dict.values()))
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? By posting a question and answer to it yourself at same time?

Comment: @MayankPorwal see [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Yes, it's a Q&A (Just try "asking a question" and you'll see Stackoverflow gives you the possibility to do that). I did that because you you type that question on google, the first result is outdated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362391/how-do-you-find-the-first-key-in-a-dictionary

Comment: This is quite common here in SO actually, and also encouraged. It is also mentioned in the link I've mentioned @MayankPorwal

Comment: My Bad. Agreed.