# How can I append the list as a value to python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, helper

I have a list as follows

```
[
 {A:a,B:b,C:c},
 {D:d,E:e,F:f}
]
```

I want the dictionary to be

```
{
A:{
A:a,B:b,C:c
},
D:{
D:d,E:e,F:f
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide a valid Python structure as input. Also, why should the keys be `A` and `D`? First one? Alphabetical order? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```py
l = [{'A':'a', 'B':'b', 'C':'c'},
     {'D':'d', 'E':'e', 'F':'f'}]

d = {}
for dct in l:
    d[next(iter(dct))] = dct

print(d)
```

Output:

```py
{'A': {'A': 'a', 'B': 'b', 'C': 'c'},
 'D': {'D': 'd', 'E': 'e', 'F': 'f'}}
```

Comment: `next(iter(dct))` is a much better way to get the first key, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362391/how-do-you-find-the-first-key-in-a-dictionary

Answer (score 0):

try this:

> 

```
returned_dict={} 
L=[
 {'A':'a','B':'b','C':'c'},
 {'D':'d','E':'e','F':'f'}
]
for item in L:
    returned_dict[sorted(item)[0]]=item
```