# print the value of the first key in dictionary using key() method

Tags: python, key

```
pyDic= {'1': 'MEMBER1', '2': 'MEMBER2' ,'3': 'MEMBER3', '4': 'MEMBER4' , '5': 'MEMBER5'}
print(pyDic.keys(1))
```

Comment: Hi. I encourage you to read the documentation of python dictionaries first. dict.keys() gives a view on the dictionary on which we can't write stg like .keys(1). we can't write something like pyDic.keys(1) as .keys() doesn't take any arguments.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects

You can do the trick by just next(pyDic.keys()) for more things regarding next() and iterators please read the documentation

Comment: @rdas That will induce a TypeError

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you find the first key in a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362391/how-do-you-find-the-first-key-in-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

To get the first value from a dictionary you can do this:

```
pyDic= {'1': 'MEMBER1', '2': 'MEMBER2' ,'3': 'MEMBER3', '4': 'MEMBER4' , '5': 'MEMBER5'}

print(next(iter(pyDic.values())))
```

The dictionary function *values()* returns a reference to a dict_values class. This can be converted to an iterator with *iter()* then call *next()* on the iterator to get the first value.

Another option is to create a list from the dict_values class and then take the 0th element as follows:

```
print(list(pyDic.values())[0])
```

You can also unpack as follows:

```
value, *_ = pyDic.values()
print(value)
```

**Output:**

```
MEMBER1
```

Comment: Don't just post code, explain how it works.

Comment: sorry, thank you for reminding me