# TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code that errors out in python3:

```
self.instance_id = get_instance_metadata(data='meta-data/instance-id').keys()[0]

TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable
```

I changed my code and I get different error (I guess I need more experience):

```
self.instance_id = get_instance_metadata(list(data='meta-data/instance-id').keys())[0]

TypeError: list() takes no keyword arguments
```

Comment: Just `list(get_instance_metadata(data='meta-data/instance-id').keys())[0]`

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. SO is a Q&A site, but you haven't asked a question. It looks like you want to ask, "How can I fix this?", to which the answer is, you put `list()` in the wrong place; it should be `list(get_instance_metadata(...).keys())[0]`. Although, I'm not sure how helpful that is, because it's kind of strange to get the first element from a dict. Plus, if the dict could be very large, converting it to `list` could be wasteful. Beware the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832).

Comment: The second attempt failed due to a typo, but the first one was not a typo, and the underlying question "How do I get the first key from a `dict`?" is a reasonable question. That said, I should have caught that it was [a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30362391/364696).

Comment: @wjandrea: With modern insertion-ordered `dict`s, the concept of "first key in a `dict`" is more useful than it used to be. Pre-3.6, yeah, "first key" really meant "arbitrary key", but it's more meaningful than that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.keys()` is a `set`-like view, not a *sequence*, and you can only index sequences.

If you just want the first key, you can manually create an iterator for the `dict` (with `iter`) and advance it once (with `next`):

```
self.instance_id = next(iter(get_instance_metadata(data='meta-data/instance-id')))
```

Your second attempt was foiled by mistakes in where you performed the conversion to `list`, and should have been:

```
self.instance_id = list(get_instance_metadata(data='meta-data/instance-id').keys())[0]  # The .keys() is unnecessary, but mostly harmless
```

but it would be less efficient than the solution I suggest, as your solution would have to make a shallow copy of the *entire* set of keys as a `list` just to get the first element (big-O `O(n)` work), where `next(iter(thedict))` is `O(1)`.